# how to fix this border issue

Tags: ios, swift

I am using a border shadow, it is working fine till iPhone 6s but in greater variant the border is not coming.

I hierarchy is as:
tableView --> cell--> view(parentView)--> objects

```
   created extension for uiView:

 func addViewShadow(offset: CGSize, radius: CGFloat, color: UIColor, opacity: Float, cornerRadius: CGFloat? = nil) {
    self.layer.shadowOffset = offset
    self.layer.shadowRadius = radius
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = opacity
    self.layer.masksToBounds = false
    self.layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
    if let r = cornerRadius {

        self.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: r).cgPath
        self.layer.cornerRadius = r
        //            self.clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

used as in class:

cell.parentView.addViewShadow(offset: CGSize.zero, radius: 2, color: UIColor.darkGray, opacity: 1, cornerRadius: 5)

image:

[image]

Comment: just make sure the auto layout constraints for the table is working fine and don't forget setNeedsDisplay() may it help

Comment: I don't even know a guy named `bounds`.

Comment: draw that in the view's `-layoutSubviews()` or `-draw(rect:)` method instead, when the view's bounds are evaluated for the current screen.

Answer (score 0):

Move your code for adding shadow to `layoutSubviews`.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
//your code here
    }
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Best Solution of this issue is to give a white colour to your view which you putted in your cell

Change the colour from default to white its the best solution try it :)